# Functions to return a structure in c

Tags: c

I have a fight game between 4 Magicians and 1 Demon in C.

Each of them have 3 attributes :

- NAME
- PV(Life points)
- PM(Magic points)

I had to create a structure for Magician and Demon so i wrote :

```
struct Magician{

      char name_magician[20];
      int pm;
      int pv;

};

struct Demon{

  char name_demon[20];
  int pv;
  int pm;

};


typedef struct Magician magician;

typedef struct Demon demon;
```

Now:

How can i create a function that create a Demon?

And a function to create a group of 4 Magicians ?

What i tried in main function basically the simple :

```
demon d1;
d1.name_demon="demonx123";
d1.pv=15;
d1.pm=20;
```

Comment: Tip: allocate on the heap and return a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a single structure from a function is easy: You do it just like any other function returning a value:

```
demon create_demon(void)
{
    demon d;
    // Initialize the demon

    return d;
}
```

Returning an array of multiple structures is a little harder, but just like for returning a single structure is the same as returning any value, returning an array of structures is exactly the same as returning an array of any other value. This can be done either by allocating on the heap, and returning a pointer. Or by passing a pointer to the first element as an argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation i got it

Answer (score 1):

To make group of Magician, you can use array of Magician structure.
Something like...

```
> struct Magician m[4];
```

Use this statement in a function.
This will create you 4 members of Magician.Now you can initialize them as you are doing for demon.

Comment: The problem with this is that it can't be returned, which I think the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can easily create your demons.

```
 struct demon *createDemon(char *name, int pv, int pm){
     struct demon *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct demon));

     if (tmp == NULL || sizeof(tmp->name) < strlen(name))
         return NULL;

     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
         tmp->name[i] = name[i];
     tmp->pm = pm;
     tmp->pv = pv;

     return tmp;
}
```

And in case you wonder, this way you can remove it again.

```
void removeDemon(struct demon *dtr){
    if (dtr != NULL){
        free(dtr);
    }
}
```

To make your structure a little less static you should however change 
the way you initialize the name of your *creature*, like:

```
struct demon{
    char *name;
    int pv;
    int pm;
};
```

This way you can allocate the space you need for your *creatures* name dynamically like:

```
struct demon *createDemon(char *name, int pv, int pm){

    // Try to allocate demon structure. If fail return NULL
    struct demon *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct demon));
    if (tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Try to allocate demon name. If fail, return NULL
    tmp->name = malloc(strlen(name));
    if (tmp->name == NULL) {
        free(tmp->name);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Set Variables and return structure
    tmp->name = name;
    tmp->pm = pm;
    tmp->pv = pv;

    return tmp;
}
```

And you need to renew your removal function as well to remove the allocated space created for the name like:

```
void removeDemon(struct demon *dtr){
    if (dtr != NULL){
        free(dtr->name);
        free(dtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: The exact same way

Answer (score 1):

```
 struct Magician *m = malloc (sizeof(struct Magician)*NumOfMagitians);
```

And return the pointer